# How to animate a circle for a clock effect in SVG animation using CSS3 or VanillaJS?

Tags: html, css, svg

I have the following code:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" id="city-total-v2" version="1.1" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 1000 1000" enable-background="new 0 0 1000 1000" xml:space="preserve">
<g id="Block1board">
 <g>
  <linearGradient id="SVGID_492_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="206.0166" y1="603.585" x2="165.4035" y2="493.2244">
   <stop offset="0" style="stop-color: rgb(48, 66, 204);" />
   <stop offset="1" style="stop-color: rgb(48, 66, 204); stop-opacity: 0;" />
  </linearGradient>
  <polygon fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" fill="url(#SVGID_492_)" points="109.77,675.92 109.77,488.97 262.38,422.89 262.38,609.83 109.77,675.92  " />
  <polygon fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" fill="#3042CC" points="116.19,721.81 116.19,721.42 109.7,716.77 109.7,611.43 262.73,540.88 269.11,545.97 269.21,545.93 269.21,651.25 118.96,720.53 116.63,721.74 116.52,721.66 116.19,721.81  " />
  <polygon fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" fill="#0A2C60" points="116.19,721.81 116.19,721.42 109.7,716.77 109.7,611.43 201.92,682.28 118.96,720.53 116.63,721.74 116.52,721.66 116.19,721.81  " />
  <path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" fill="#FFFFFF" d="M134.53,655.73c0.08-19.16,10.9-37.98,24.14-42 c13.24-4.03,23.92,8.25,23.83,27.41c-0.08,19.16-10.9,37.97-24.14,42S134.44,674.88,134.53,655.73L134.53,655.73z" style="     display: block; " />
  <linearGradient id="SVGID_493_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="161.1758" y1="638.1934" x2="161.1758" y2="663.8602">
   <stop offset="0" style="stop-color: rgb(48, 66, 204);" />
   <stop offset="1" style="stop-color: rgb(75, 235, 201);" />
  </linearGradient>
  <path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" fill="url(#SVGID_493_)" d="M142.87,672.1L142.87,672.1l17.48-22.04v-32.18 c10.75-2.23,19.2,8.14,19.13,23.96c-0.07,16.5-9.39,32.71-20.8,36.18C152.31,679.96,146.63,677.51,142.87,672.1L142.87,672.1z" style="     transform: rotate3d(0, 16deg); " />
 </g>
</svg>
```

Click on **Run code snippet** to see the demo.

I want to fill the circle using the gradient shape (as a clock would do)

Is this possible using CSS3 or VanillaJS?? Any advice are much appreciated

Comment: Techically this is possible on some browsers using CSS3 and keyframes with the new SVG2 method using `{ d: path(...); }`.  However browser support is only just becoming available. So I would say it is not really a practical solution right now.  You could do it with SMIL or JS animation however.

Comment: What is SMIL?  I've added the Vanilla JS question in my topic.

Comment: SMIL is referring to the animation elements that are part of the SVG standard.  For example the `<animate>` element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to make it work I've commented out your last path, and now I'm drawing it dynamically. With every step of the animation the path changes it's shape.

To start the animation please click on the svg canvas.

Please read my comments in the code

```js
let c = {x:159,y:648.13}//the center of the shape
let tilt = 16;//the tilt angle
// the radiuses of the ellipse 
let R = 30.5;
let r = 17.8;
let steps = 360;// number of frames for the animation
let step = 2*Math.PI/steps;
let rid = null;// request animation id
let ry = [];// an array for the points used to draw the ellipse
//rotate the path
test.setAttributeNS(null,"transform",`rotate(${tilt} ${c.x} ${c.y})` )


let a = -Math.PI/2 -(16 * Math.PI/180);// starting angle

function Frame(){
  rid= requestAnimationFrame(Frame);
  // with every step a new point is pushed in the points array
  if(a < 3*Math.PI/2){a+=step
  let x = c.x + r*Math.cos(a);
  let y = c.y + R*Math.sin(a);
  ry.push({x,y})
  // build the d attribute for the path
  let d = `M${c.x},${c.y}`;

ry.map(e=>{
  d+=`L${e.x},${e.y}`
})
 d+="Z" 
// reset the d attribute for the path                     
test.setAttributeNS(null,"d",d);
 }else{
 // when everithing is done, stop the animation
   cancelAnimationFrame(rid)
 }
}

// restart animation on click
svg.addEventListener("click",()=>{
  if(rid){cancelAnimationFrame(rid); rid="null"}
  a = -Math.PI/2 -(16 * Math.PI/180);
  ry = [];
  Frame()
})
```

```css
svg{border:1px solid}
```

```html
<svg id="svg" viewBox="100 400 200 350" width="200">
  <defs>
    <linearGradient id="SVGID_492_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="206.0166" y1="603.585" x2="165.4035" y2="493.2244">
    <stop offset="0" style="stop-color: rgb(48, 66, 204);" />
    <stop offset="1" style="stop-color: rgb(48, 66, 204); stop-opacity: 0;" /></linearGradient>
  <linearGradient id="SVGID_493_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="161.1758" y1="638.1934" x2="161.1758" y2="663.8602">
    <stop offset="0" style="stop-color: rgb(48, 66, 204);" />
    <stop offset="1" style="stop-color: rgb(75, 235, 201);" />
  </linearGradient>  
  </defs> 
  
<g id="Block1board">
  <polygon fill="url(#SVGID_492_)" points="109.77,675.92 109.77,488.97 262.38,422.89 262.38,609.83 109.77,675.92  " />
  <polygon fill="#3042CC" points="116.19,721.81 116.19,721.42 109.7,716.77 109.7,611.43 262.73,540.88 269.11,545.97 269.21,545.93 269.21,651.25 118.96,720.53 116.63,721.74 116.52,721.66 116.19,721.81  " />
  <polygon fill="#0A2C60" points="116.19,721.81 116.19,721.42 109.7,716.77 109.7,611.43 201.92,682.28 118.96,720.53 116.63,721.74 116.52,721.66 116.19,721.81" />
  <path fill="#FFFFFF" d="M134.53,655.73c0.08-19.16,10.9-37.98,24.14-42 c13.24-4.03,23.92,8.25,23.83,27.41c-0.08,19.16-10.9,37.97-24.14,42S134.44,674.88,134.53,655.73L134.53,655.73z" />
   
  <!--<path fill="url(#SVGID_493_)" d="M142.87,672.1L142.87,672.1l17.48-22.04v-32.18 c10.75-2.23,19.2,8.14,19.13,23.96c-0.07,16.5-9.39,32.71-20.8,36.18C152.31,679.96,146.63,677.51,142.87,672.1L142.87,672.1z" style="transform: rotate3d(0, 16deg); " />-->
  
  <path id="test" d="" fill="url(#SVGID_493_)"  />  
  </g>
</svg>
```

### UPDATE

In order to stop the animation at a different angle I added `let stopAngle = (240*Math.PI/180)-Math.PI/2`; In this case is stopping at 240 degs. If you need to make the animations slower change the `step` duration. Try for example `step = 0.008;` instead of `step = 2*Math.PI/steps`

```js
let c = {x:150,y:150}
let R = 120;
let r = 90;
let steps = 360;
let step = 0.005//2*Math.PI/steps;
let rid = null;
let ry = []


let a = -Math.PI/2;// starting angle

let stopAngle = (240*Math.PI/180)-Math.PI/2

function Frame(){
  rid= requestAnimationFrame(Frame);
  if(a < stopAngle){a+=step
  let x = c.x + r*Math.cos(a);
  let y = c.y + R*Math.sin(a);
  ry.push({x,y})
  let d = `M${c.x},${c.y}`;

ry.map(e=>{
  d+=`L${e.x},${e.y}`
})
 d+="Z" 
                     
test.setAttributeNS(null,"d",d);
 }else{
   cancelAnimationFrame(rid)
 }
}

Frame();
```

Comment: Thank you, that's impressive and helpful.

Comment: Thanks, this really what I wanted, Is there a way I can play with the animation duration? And is there a way to stop the circle at 70% instead of getting him full ? I presum this happen in `a < 3 * Math.PI / 2`, what is it exactly?

Comment: I don't understand you. Can you give me more details?

Comment: How can I double the animation duration?

Comment: Thanks a lot that's awesome!